# Wrong date/year on passport stamp upon US arrival

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I entered the USA via Washington DC Dulles airport on 28 August, 2021 on a B2 visa. The immigration officer put an oval shaped stamp for 28 August, 2021 and hand wrote how long can I stay. Here comes the error. I guess he gave me a 6 month entry permit, till 27 February, 2022. But, he wrote 27 February, **2021**. It's clearly a mistake which I realized later, I can't stay till 27 February, 2021 if I entered on 28 August, 2021.

Will it be a problem? Should I contact someone? Do they have any electronic record of how many days can I stay?

Comment: Check on https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home

Comment: Thanks a ton. I could find my record based on the link you provided. It's written on the I94 that: Admit Until Date : 02/27/2022. But, still it's written 02/27/2021 on my passport. Should I be worried or contact someone?

Comment: I’m pretty sure we had a similar question a few months ago. Can’t find it though.

Comment: Thanks. Do you remember the ultimate resolution he got?

Comment: I bet that immigration officer was having a BadDay™ and that you weren't the only person he wrote the wrong year for.

Comment: I had this happen to me once - they gave me 2 weeks rather than 2 years.  Thankfully I was still at the airport when I noticed (it was a Canada->US flight so I was actually at the departure airport where US immigration occurs) so I backtracked to US immigration, they took me to Secondary, and fixed it for me. Took about 10 minutes all up.

Answer (score 2):

> Do they have an electronic record?

Yes, as mentioned in the comments, https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov shows the electronic I-94 record. If it's different than what's written, that means one of them was a mistake. Print a copy of the electronic I-94 and save it forever, as evidence that the written date on the entry stamp was a mistake. The site usually won't show this record after you leave the US, so print it now.

> Will it [the wrong written date] be a problem?

Maybe or maybe not. If you're leaving before the electronic I-94 end date and not returning to the US for a while, it's probably fine. OTOH, if you apply for an H-1B or another immigration status that requires adjudication in the future, it could be an issue to have to explain why it's a mistake.

> Should I contact someone?

It's up to you, but I would request a correction just to be extra careful. <strike>Most CBP ports of entry</strike>[CBP's Deferred Inspection Sites](https://www.cbp.gov/contact/ports/deferred-inspection-sites) will make I-94 corrections in case of mistakes CBP made on the entry stamp or electronic I-94. Many of the sites are at airports and are open Monday-Friday in the morning before most international flights start to arrive. Bring all documents but mainly the passport and printout of electronic I-94, and they should correct the entry stamp.

Comment: Thank you so much. With the link given by you gentlemen, I was able to find my I-94 record. And it's showing the current date - 27 Feb 2022. I will try to show it to the airport to someone official.

Comment: Rather than going to the airport, you should contact a CBP Deferred Inspection Site.  https://www.cbp.gov/contact/ports/deferred-inspection-sites  If you are still in the DC area there is a DIS located at IAD airport, however there are others that may be nearer.

Comment: @Doc Thanks! Edited to clarify and add that link.

Comment: Why would OP have to explain anything if they apply for H1-B? They only ask for your travel history, not actual copies of entry stamps. As long as I94 is correct I wouldn’t bother doing anything, especially since this is an obvious mistake where date of departure is prior to date of return. Would be a waste of precious travel time to go correcting it.